# How to pass Form reference without the static form in the class?

Tags: c#, .net

My heading probably does not make any sense. I'm going to attempt to translate my problem to English by showing you an example, since I don't know how to word this. *(English is my 3rd language)*

So Basically, I want to be able to do this in my class:

```
public void beheerToegang(ref Form frm)
{    

}
```

Instead of this *(static reference the actual name of my form)*:

```
public void beheerToegang(ref frmInkomsteBlad frm)
{    

}
```

Comment: Actually it still doesn't have any sense. You don't need to use `ref` for reference type. And I see no reason why you can't use `public void beheerToegang(Form frm)` beside the naming convention :).

Comment: can you explain what you want to achieve here

Comment: Passing by reference requires an *exact* match on the type, hard C# rule.  Very low odds that you actually need *ref* here, especially since you didn't explain why you need it.  So try it without.

Comment: Our system makes use of the Datagridview control to display data. We need to incorporate a couple of changes. Some are security related and other just visual. The idea was to create a class that will do all this, which worked fine for the security changes, but the visual things, like changing backgrounds of DGV controls, additional textbox and combobox event handlers, ext. 
The solution is too large to make these changes quickly, so we wondered if there was a 2nd option.
ps. The code loops the controls in the form to make changes. This will enable us to just deploy a dll (update) in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I see the picture about what problem you are encountering.

First, you do not need to add ref in the method (and consider better naming). It is already referenced object

```
public void beheerToegang(Form frm)
{    

}
```

Next, you can use the method as is, from your custom Form, example (not tested code):

```
frmInkomsteBlad form1 = new frmInkomsteBlad();
beheerToegang(form1);
```

Then access it like:

```
public void beheerToegang(Form frm)
{    
  string formTitle = frm.Text;
}
```

However you cannot access the defined properties / fields in custom form frmInkomsteBlad. Example:

```
public class frmInkomsteBlad : Form{
  public string CustomString{get;set;} // this property cannot be accessed
}
```

However there are ways to workaround this, first is use typecasting:

```
public void beheerToegang(Form frm)
{   
  if(frm is frmInkomsteBlad){
    frmInkomsteBlad typeCastedForm = (frmInkomsteBlad)frm;
    string customString = typeCastedForm.CustomString;
  }
}
```

The above example is bad practice, but easy to implement. If you are more concern for better practice, consider using [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead. Example:

```
public interface ICustomForm{
  string Title{get;set;}
  string CustomString{get;set;}
  object CustomObject{get;set;}
}
```

Implement it in your frmInkomsteBlad Form.

```
public class frmInkomsteBlad : Form, ICustomForm{
  public string Title{
    get{
     return this.Text;
    }
    set{
     this.Text = value;
    }
  }

  //other implementation here
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
public void beheerToegang(ICustomForm frm)
{   
  string customString = frm.CustomString;
  string title = frm.Title;
  object customObject = frm.CustomObject;
}
```

Comment: You're right, but using interfaces here is not just a concern of better practice, since your first workaround just moves the ref to the Form inside the body of the method, without actually removing it.

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli, I don't quite get what do you mean by "without actually removing it".
Isn't it considered at bad practice having specify the class inside the method, and causing using interface is a concern of good practice?
I am just starting to use Interfaces too BTW, so need to learn more.

Comment: I just mean that using interfaces is the right way to go here (+1 for that). Casting inside the body of the method is not good, since you still have a reference to the class frmInkomsteBlad, so you can't remove the reference to the assembly where it is defined. You're right that one is good practice and the other one bad practice, but in this case the difference is more substantial.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. Feeling a bit stupid.
We are asp.net developers, so we are use to centralizing code. This is our first winForms project in years. 
Don't even get me started on the naming conventions that this company is forcing us to use.

Thanks a mill @Fendy. Interfaces it is!

Answer (score 1):

can you explain you problem a little bit more?
Why do you use the keyword ref? Form is an object, so if you want to manipulate it, you can just use

```
public void beheerToegang(Form frm)
```

Is the problem in 'how to call' the method beheerToegang or is it something else. It's not clear to me? 
It seems you're Dutch, you can ask the question in Dutch if you want to. It is my native language.

If the problem is simply calling the method, then you can use:

```
beheerToegang(ref yourformname);
```

Comment: Please see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/ for the official policy on non-English use on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't know that. Won't happen again.

Comment: Thank you @Erwin van Dijk for the offer to help me in Dutch. I did find a solution though. Thanks

Comment: @magos thanks for pointing out the language T&C of this forum.

I do think that I'll find it difficult to locate an Afrikaans (Kitchen Dutch) forum, but if you can point me to one it will be greatly appreciated.